# Understanding part of the proof that $\int_{x=-1}^1P_L(x)P_M(x)\,\rm{d} x =0\quad\text{(for}\,\, L\ne M)$

Tags: proof-explanation, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Starting from Legendre's Differential Equation $$\begin{align*}
(1-x^2)y^{\prime\prime}-2xy^{\prime}+L(L+1)y=0\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

In the text that follows $P_L(x)$, $P_M(x)$ represent *general* Legendre Polynomials.

We can rewrite $(1)$ in the form $$\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_L\acute (x)\Big)+L(L+1)P_L(x)=0\tag{2}$$

Now after writing the same for $P_M(x)$
$$\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_M\acute (x)\Big)+M(M+1)P_M(x)=0\tag{3}$$

and then we multiply $(2)$ by $P_M(x)$  to get $$\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_L\acute (x)\Big)P_M(x)+L(L+1)P_L(x)P_M(x)=0\tag{4}$$ and $(3)$ by $P_L(x)$ to get
$$\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_M\acute(x)\Big)P_L(x)+M(M+1)P_L(x)P_M(x)=0\tag{5}$$

subtracting $(5)$ from $(4)$ gets us to

$$\color{red}{P_M(x)\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_L\acute (x)\Big)-P_L(x)\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_M\acute(x)\Big)}+\Big(L(L+1)-M(M+1)\Big)P_L(x)P_M(x)=0\tag{6}$$

To continue this proof I need to show that the first two terms of $(6)$ marked in $\color{red}{\rm{red}}$:
$$\color{red}{P_M(x)\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_L\acute (x)\Big)-P_L(x)\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)P_M\acute(x)\Big)}$$ can be written as 
$$\color{blue}{\dfrac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}x}\Big((1-x^2)(P_M(x)P_L\acute (x)-P_L(x)P_M\acute (x))\Big)}$$

Is anyone able to demonstrate how to reach the $\color{blue}{\rm{blue}}$ from the $\color{red}{\rm{red}}$ expression by showing the intermediate steps? Or some hints would be very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the normal add and subtract the same term technique, for example:
$$
A(b C')' - C(b A')' = A(b C')' - C(b A')' + A'b C'-A'b C'
= (A b C')' -(A' b C)' = (A b C' - A' b C)' = (b(A C' - C A'))'
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer; Could you please also show intermediate steps on how you got from $A(b C')' - C(b A')' + A'b C'-A'b C'$ to $(A b C')' -(A' b C)'$? I can't quite figure it out by myself; I think you factorized it somehow, but not sure. Regards.

Comment: @BLAZE Hi, collect the first and third terms from the first formula and use the inverse of the derivative rule (ab)' = a'b + ab', you get the first term of the second formula. In the same fashion the second and fourth terms from the first formula ends as the second term of the second formula.

Comment: Hi again, so doing what you said with the first and third terms: $A(b C')'+A'bC'=A(b'C'+bC'')+A'bC'=Ab'C'+AbC''+A'bC'$. But how is that equal to $(AbC')'$? Sorry, I want to accept your answer but I still don't understand.

Comment: Use your example, you should consider bC' as a single term as it appears in both terms of the left most expression. Let's use B to represent it, then (with $bC'  = B$) we have: $A(bC')' + A'bC' = AB' + A'B = (AB)'$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give a great answer and explanation in the comments, it is appreciated.

Comment: @BLAZE You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't an answer to the question as stated but it shows why they are orthogonal.

Start with $-m(m+1)P_m(x) = \frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)P_m'(x))$ multiply both sides by $P_l(x)$ and integrate over $x\in [-1,1]$, after an integration by parts we get

$$
(m)(m+1)\int_{-1}^1 P_m(x) P_l(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^1 P_l'(x) (1-x^2) P_m'(x)\, \mathrm{d} x
$$

Similarly start with $-l(l+1)P_l(x) = \frac{d}{dx} ((1-x^2)P'_l(x))$ and multiply both sides by $P_m(x)$ and integrate over $x\in [-1,1]$, after we integrate this by parts we get

$$
l(l+1)\int_{-1}^1 P_l(x)P_m(x)\, \mathrm{d} x = \int_{-1}^1 P_m'(x) (1-x^2) P'_l(x)\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comparing both of these equation's right hand sides we see that 
$$0=(m(m+1)-l(l+1)) \int_{-1}^1 P_l(x)P_m(x)\, \mathrm{d} x$$ so either the integral is zero or $m(m+1)=l(l+1)$, but the latter is only possible if $l=m$ so if $l\not = m$ we must have that the integral is zero.

Comment: That's great, thanks for sharing that information